# does count automatically sum up similar values without a group by statement

Tags: mysql, group-by, count

THIS IS THE INPUT

```
    team_1  team_2   winner
    
    Aus     India   India
    Eng      NZ      NZ
    India    SL     India
    SA       Eng    Eng
    SL       Aus    Aus
```

OUTPUT

```
team_name  matches_played     no_of_wins

India      2                  2
 SL        2                  NULL
 SA        1                  NULL
Eng        2                   1
Aus        2                   1
NZ         1                   1
```

This is the MYSQL solution for the problem:

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT team_1 team_name,winner FROM icc_world_cup
UNION ALL
SELECT team_2 team_name,winner FROM icc_world_cup)

SELECT DISTINCT team_name,                                              # first column
COUNT(team_name) as Macthes_played,                                     #second column
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
(SELECT IF(team_1=winner,team_1,team_2) win_team FROM icc_world_cup )a 
WHERE team_name=win_team GROUP BY win_team) no_of_wins                  #third column
FROM CTE GROUP BY team_name
```

The above output is what I got from the code which I have written but the problem is
If I remove the **GROUP BY** statement in the **third column** that is

> GROUP BY win_team

Then the output was something like this

```
team_name  matches_played     no_of_wins
    
    India      2                  2
     SL        2                  0
     SA        1                  0
    Eng        2                  1
    Aus        2                  1
    NZ         1                  1
```

How the count is able sum up team india's wins that is 2 without a group by statement, does it have something to with the where clause condition and
**NOTICE** that the **NULL** values in the third column were replaced by 0's.

How is it possible that without a group by statement my count function is able to sum up similar values and how the null are changed to 0.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a union approach here:

```sql
SELECT team_name, COUNT(*) AS matches_played, SUM(win) AS no_of_wins
FROM
(
    SELECT team_1 AS team_name, IF(team_1 = winner, 1, 0) AS win FROM yourTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT team_2, IF(team_2 = winner, 1, 0) FROM yourTable
) t
GROUP BY team_name;
```

Comment: In MySQL `IF()` is excess, `SELECT team_1 AS team_name, team_1 = winner AS win FROM yourTable` is enough.